# Bourbon Bitters and Neat Column Number Set to 8, not 12

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I've just recently added Bourbon, Bitters, and Neat to my rails application. I'm trying to set the number of grid-columns to 12 but for some reason it's 8.

I've done all of the following:

- `@import 'bitters/bitters'` is after `bourbon` and before `neat` in
  my manifest file.
- I've uncommented the Neat Override variables in
  _grid-settings. Specifically, I've set `$grid-columns` to 12.
- I'm importing `_grid-settings` and `neat-helpers` in the bitters manifest file (which is then imported in the the application manifest file).

I know that the _grid-settings sheet is working because I can change every other variable EXCEPT `grid-columns`. I haven't specified grid-columns anywhere else, so I'm totally perplexed!

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using the default Bitters _grid-settings.scss file, you'll have two lines setting the breakpoints:

```
$medium-screen-up: new-breakpoint(min-width $medium-screen 4);
$large-screen-up: new-breakpoint(min-width $large-screen 8);
```

Regardless of what you set $grid_columns to, those breakpoints are setting the columns to "4" and "8" respectively -- as a columns value is being passed into the new-breakpoint function. So, if you were viewing your project on a $large-screen size, you would have seen 8 columns with the visual-grid.

Comment: do you happen to know why bitters defaults to a 8 grid setting for Neat?

Comment: I'm really not sure. I always set mine to 12, regardless of break-point, as I've always done responsive that way and so it's easier to work out the structure. I suspect it's just personal preference.

Comment: I just guess it's just REALLY confusing when using Neat and Bitters together because Neat defaults to 12 columns and then Bitters defaults to 8 columns (thus overriding the Neat default)...

Answer (score 2):

Turns out my columns were being set correctly. What was being set incorrectly was the visual grid. The new breakpoints in the grid-settings files were changing my screen to 8 columns, and then the visual grid was being displayed that way. I don't understand why they were separate but I ended up commenting out the new break points for now and now the visual grid lines up with my desired columns.